# Joomla event onContentAfterSave not firing

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to run some code when a Joomla plugin config is saved and I've gone through the documentation and tried all content events I could find there with a `die();` in them and none is triggered.

```
public function onContentAfterSave($context, $article, $isNew)
    {
        die();
    }
```

Can anyone point out how I can achieve this please?

Comment: didn't think it would be helpful since in the question I already say that I tried all events with a die on them but edited with an example of one of them.

Comment: Have you enabled your plugin ?

Comment: Yes, would be funny otherwise though.

Comment: Still sometimes happens :) Also have you check if other function are working or not ? like *onContentBeforeDisplay*.

Comment: Yea I've literally added functions for all content events in my plugin and none fired except onContentPrepareForm

Comment: are you trying this in content plugin try http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content

Comment: The way you have phrased it makes it sound a bit strange .. " to run some code when a joomla plugin config is saved"  ... com_plugin doesn't have the content events since it is not a content component (the way com_content, com_contact etc are)  but it has a form which is why it would run a form event.   
So your plugin event such as the onContentAfterSave will run mainly when you save  an article.   
Are you saying your save of an article does not die?

Comment: Forgive me if I'm not explaining well, I've never touched joomla until a couple days ago. I have a system plugin which has options, so when you go to the administration->Extensions->Plug-in Manager->My plugin you can see the options and save them. What I'm looking for is an event that is fired when these options are saved.

Comment: You would need to add an event that was triggered inside of com_plugins. You can't really do that very easily.  Instead I would go ahead and use the form save event.  You context would be com_plugins.plugin.  You would need to make a different plugin that would respond to that event (not the same plugin).  Plugins are listeners and they get triggered when events happen so you would be in a weird hall of mirrors to have a plugin respond to its own events.

Answer (score 0):

onContentBeforeSave does just what the name suggests: fires before you save **content** not plugin configuration.  In order to catch the saved plugin configuration you have no Joomla events available.

So you can check if the plugin configuration was changed at every page load in the administrator: the sequence would be:

Your plugin onContentBeforeDisplay (or some other events you don't need for your business logic) runs in the administrator only (which is the not the default behaviour, you'll need to check and exit if it's frontend to avoid slowing down your site) and in that event handler you check for a custom configuration field: to achieve this you just insert a custom (hidden) value in the plugin configuration.  When your event fires, you load the plugin configuration and check if it's the default value or not, remove it from the configuration object and save it again to the db; so next time the user loads it it will change again, setting the default value. Not nice but it will work.